# Multiple Netty Clients sending data to one Netty server

Tags: multithreading, netty

I am using Netty 3.9.5 and I have a simple client server setup which I got from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_%28software%29#Netty_TCP_Example. I have expanded the example to send a Java search plan object from the client to the server.  With help from follow users on this site, I have been able to get this program to function as desired.

I now want to have my reader/server program accept multiple clients at the same time.  I thought I would take my original pipeline factory code listed below:

```
channelFactory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossThreadPool,
            workerThreadPool);
    this.bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(channelFactory);
    this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                    new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers
                            .cacheDisabled(getClass().getClassLoader())),
                    new ServerMessageHandler());
        }
    });
```

and make this change:

```
channelFactory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossThreadPool,workerThreadPool, 3);
```

I thought this would create 3 worker threads within the workerThreadPool, which in turn would be able to handle 3 client connections.  This does not work.  The first client connection works as expected but the 2nd connection eventually throws a connect timeout exception.

Questions:

1. Is my assumption about the workerThreadPool correct and if yes, what did I forget?
2. Right now my code still only uses one port for the connect.  Do I need a unique port for each possible connection?  I have not seen an example of this.  Do I need to tweak the bind method or the acceptor.isBound method for possible multiple connections?

   ```
   public boolean connect() {
   boolean status = false; // assume failure

   final int LISTEN_PORT = 53233;

   /*
    * We use a channel when attempting to bind the ServerBootstrap to
    * ensure if the operation was successful
    */
   acceptor = this.bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(LISTEN_PORT));

   /*
    * We make sure the Server could bind to the port by calling the
    * isBound() method in the Channel class.
    */
   if (!acceptor.isBound()) {
       logger.error(ErrorMessage.SERVER_UNABLE_TO_BIND + LISTEN_PORT);

       status = false;
   } else {
       status = true;
       logger.info(Message.SERVER_CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL + LISTEN_PORT
               + "!" + Message.SERVER_AWAITING_CONNECTIONS);
   }

   return status;
   }
   ```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the worker pool is linked to the number of concurrent connections. What kind of executor you passed as worker? I would suggest to use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`. In would suggest in this case to not set any third value in your NioServerSocketChannelFactory, since it will take by default NumberOfCore*2, so letting as you did before.

Also I suppose your ServerMessageHandler does not block for ever (or very long), because if it does, then you have to add just before it in the pipeline something like `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` to free the worker thread.

Comment: I use Executors.newCachedThreadPool already, so I should be good there.  I will look into OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.  Thank you